# Questions with bounties awarded sometimes show the awarding users' names as "false"

Tags: support, bounties, tooltips

For example, see: [prolog - Rearranging variable_names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308115/rearranging-variable-names/21468591#21468591)

The markup for the awarded bounty badge reads:

```
<span class="bounty-award d-block ta-center" title="This answer has been awarded bounties worth 2700 reputation by false, false, false, false, false, false and false">+2700</span>
```

Additional image in case this is browser dependent:[image: Image of broken broken alt text for a badge showing "false, false, false, false, false, false and false" instead of the appropriate names.]

As viewed in Firefox 65.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a bug.

The user who asked the question is named "false". Due to the number of bounties they've offered on Stack Overflow (totaling [31,300 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=bounties&sort=offered&page=1)), it seems like they were the one who put all the bounties on that answer.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/981037 and the revisions https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21308115/revisions tell the story.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's pretty hilarious actually.

Comment: The extreme number of bounties offered by that user makes their rep graph most wonderfully spiky!